# How do I add HTTP request headers to a Hyperlink in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm generating a Hyperlink programmatically with reference to the contents of another cell using `=HYPERLINK(B5&"?some_query, "my_text")`.

But there's no option here to add a HTTP request header (I'd like to add a secret in the header because it is ill-advised to put secrets in query params).

How do I add a header?

(Somewhat side tangent, the hyperlink generated does a GET. Bonus points if we can change it to POST, tho not totally necessary...)

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. It's not possible by using built-in functions but you could create a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions). If this is something that might be a solution for you, learn about the [Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch).

Comment: Related??: [Google App Script: URLFetchApp.fetch with header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35133610/1330560)

Comment: I ended up going with a custom function which uses URLFetchApp. Thanks Tedinoz!